# Can I compile using VS2008's C++ compiler using VS2010 and only the Server 2008 Platform SDK?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'd rather not install the entire VS 2008 installation given that I'm not going to be using anything other than the compiler. Will VS 2010's multitargeting work correctly using only the [Platform SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F26B1AA4-741A-433A-9BE5-FA919850BDBF&displaylang=en) instead of the full VS2008 install?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The custom setup options are not nearly fine-grained enough to allow you to leave the big chunks like the IDE out.  It isn't just the SDK that's used, at least the VC subdirectory needs to be there.  And bits of Common7, also the folder that contains the IDE.  Rename the folders, delete them later if it works out.

Comment: I'm not installing using the Visual Studio installer; I'm using the PSDK download here -> http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F26B1AA4-741A-433A-9BE5-FA919850BDBF&displaylang=en

Comment: Erm, the SDK used to contain the compiler/linker.  I think those days are over, SDK version 7.0 on my machine doesn't have them.  The msbuild .target files definitely assume a VS2008 install.  I seriously doubt it will work.

Comment: @Hans: So the answer to my question above is "No" then? :P

Comment: @Hans: Are you sure the 7.x version of the SDK doesn't have them? They won't be listed if you already have Visual Studio installed. It's listed on my box.

Comment: I can only tell you what's on my machines, VS2008 was already present.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call the .net 3.5 MSBuild from command line by digging it out of the frameworks folder within windows. I am not certain if you could repoint Visual Studio at a different copy though. More importantly, unless you have found a bug, the copy of MSBuild included in the .Net 4 framework should properly build a project targeting the 3.5 framework. So you might be jumping through some unnecessary hoops in the first place.

Comment: I don't see what the .NET Framework version has to do with C++ projects, which do not use/depend on the .NET Framework. VS2010 supports targeting the framework back to 2.x without any modification in any case.

Comment: The .Net framework is relevant because MSBuild is actually part of the framework not VS2010.

Comment: VS2010's multitargeting uses .NET 4 for everything in any case.