# Building C++ CLR app for Platform Toolset v90 in VS2010 requires Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

I've got a shiny new laptop with the latest Dev tools installed such as Visual Studio 2010.

Now I've got a task to build a C++ CLR app targeting the 2.0 runtime (this is well outside my comfort zone).  So I've specifed the v90 Platform Toolset but when I build I get:-

> error MSB8010: Specified platform toolset (v90) requires Visual Studio 2008. Please make sure that Visual Studio 2008 is installed on the machine.

Seriously, do I really need to install 2008 as well?  Is there some way round this, such as just copying in some folders from a 2008 install?

If not just how much of the VS 2008 installation do I need?

Comment: Related?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295628/can-i-compile-using-vs2008s-c-compiler-using-vs2010-and-only-the-server-2008-p

Comment: You really *do* need VS2008.  Upvote this to feel better: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/567504/targeting-frameworks-other-than-4-0-with-c-cli-project-and-v100-platform-toolset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem is that VS2010 redid how compiling in c++ (cli or not) works.  It now uses the MSBuild structure but I believe what you are trying to do will need the VCBuild framework that is not in 2010.

You may be able to get away with using the Visual Studio 2008 express to build.  If not you should only need the c++ portion of VS2008.

Do you need to use the vc90 target though? I build my c++/cli (still new myself) with the vc10 target and it builds fine. (however i am targeting the 4.0 framework referencing some 2.0 portions)

Comment: The resulting dll needs to operate in an existing 2.0 runtime environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the 'Platform Toolset' in general tab of your project settings to "inherit from parent or project defaults" it will work in most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

in *.vcxproj

`<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">`     //Globals
`<ProjectGuid>{E0047D4D-366D-4870-980B-DBB5A375BCE2}</ProjectGuid>`
`<RootNamespace>ECGConvertWrapper</RootNamespace>`
`<Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>`
`<WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>`
`<TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>` //there
`</PropertyGroup>`